# phpstorm move class without opening the file

Tags: refactoring, package, phpstorm, move, psr-0

Is it possible to MOVE CLASS in phpstorm without having to open the class file, select the class name et hit F6 ???

I have defined PSR0 source root, but it seems that it's note related to the problem

With intellij idea, you can just grab the class and put it in any package you want, it updates the namespace

Thank you

Comment: Nope -- such refactoring has to be performed on class name -- changing namespace via drag-and-drop is not (yet?) supported. I was hopping that it would work when invoked in Structure panel or with "Show members" option turned on -- but it has to have actual editor caret placed on class name to perform this. **P.S.** You have to keep in mind -- Java has better/long-established "standards" for many years as compared to PHP and its' "today(here)-this/tomorrow(there)-that"

Comment: yes ok, thank you. It's just frustrating you know. You can access Move but not Move Class. So if you want to split classes in packages you do it one by one ?

Comment: Well .. so far I had no major need to do such things (I do not call 2-3-5 files a major thing). But yes -- if I would need to move a lot of stuff such desired approach would be MUCH better.

Comment: Refactor actions are context dependant: the same Move or Rename action in Refactor menu does diff things depending on context. Right now it supports only currently implemented logic. What you're after here is a bit more advanced and needs some time to be implemented; plus devs usually implement missing/broken functionality first and only then do enhanced stuff (sometimes it takes like forever). Yes, I would like to see it working the suggested/expected way too. On related note: please vote - maybe they will implement this related request faster: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21208